# How do I get Windows 3.1 to run on modern PCs (> 512 MB of memory)?

Tags: windows-3.x

I am trying to make a bootable SD card that has Windows 3.1 loaded onto it. I only have 2 computers with 1 and 8 GB of RAM. When I load Windows from `C:\WINDOWS\WIN` on my older 1 GB RAM computer (a netbook from 2008, the HP Mini 110-1030NR to be exact), it displays the splash screen for like 1 second because computers are so fast now, and then crashes to MS-DOS. I have not tested on my more-modern computer with 8 GB of RAM (the HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF from 2013 or 2014, I'm not sure), and I have a 3rd computer (a Toshiba Sattelite C675D-S7101 from 2012) which does **not** boot from the SD card.

Comment: Do you need to natively boot into Windows 3.1? I can get it to work on DOSBOX with no issues and it can even read-write to the host's filesystem when configured correctly. I'm on a Dell Inspiron 7559 with 16 Gb of RAM, an i5 processor, and running Windows 10.

Comment: I can use a virtual machine if I can't figure out how to get the OS running on a newer computer, I am thinking of getting an old PC from the early 1980s to the late 90s

Comment: @nelson DOSBox isn't perfect for Win3.1x use. For example, you need a development build if you want the installer for [SimCity Classic Graphics](https://www.mobygames.com/game/simcity-classic-graphics) to work with the Windows release of SimCity Classic. Otherwise, it can't enumerate your emulated floppy drives under Windows and it's fundamentally designed around the assumption of installing from a floppy.

Comment: Just to be clear, DOSBox isn't perfect for Win3.1x use becuase it was never *intended* to run Windows. The author has made that clear yet people still seem to wonder why it's not being added.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer to [Windows 98 with 2GB of RAM](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2494/79) should be adaptable for Windows 3.1:

- download and extract [`HIMEMX`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/himemx/);
- edit `CONFIG.SYS` to load that instead of `HIMEM.SYS`, and specify `/MAX=262144` to limit memory to 256MiB ([the practical limit for Windows 3.*x*](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/084/Q84388/)).

This will ensure that Windows only sees 256MiB through the XMM, and should allow it to start and run.

Comment: I added HIMEM.EXE to my C:\WINDOWS folder, and changed C:\DOS\HIMEM.SYS and C:\WINDOWS\HIMEM.SYS to C:\WINDOWS\HIMEMX.EXE /max=262144 in all of the config.sys files in the dos and windows folders, now windows is complaining that himem.sys doesn't exist, I couldn't find a .sys in all of the himemx folders I downloaded from your link in the original answer

Comment: It sounds like the 256 MB limit is better described as a "practical maximum": you can give Windows more, but it will probably never be able to use it (and it will never use more than 512 MB).

Comment: @Claudia try loading both `HIMEMX.EXE` and `C:\WINDOWS\HIMEM.SYS` (I thought the former would be enough, but perhaps not).